# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: node.js, express, web-scraping, axios

I´ve the file **cases.js** to create the route I want:

```
const express = require("express");
const { requireSignin } = require("../controllers/auth");
const { getCases } = require("../controllers/cases");
const { scrapingData } = require("../scrapingData");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/cases", requireSignin, scrapingData, getCases);

module.exports = router;
```

requireSignin from **controllers/auth** looks like this:

```
exports.requireSignin = expressJwt({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  userProperty: "auth",
});
```

**scrapingData** as middleware I have:

```
const updateMongoRecords = async () => {
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
  mongoose.set("debug", true);

  Case.deleteMany({}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Successfully deleted all records");
    }
  });

  const dataPath = Path.join(__dirname, "files", "covid-data.csv");

  try {
    let headers = Object.keys(Case.schema.paths).filter(
      (k) => ["_id", "__v"].indexOf(k) === -1
    );

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let buffer = [],
        counter = 0;

      let stream = fs
        .createReadStream(dataPath)
        .pipe(csv())
        .on("error", reject)
        .on("data", async (doc) => {
          stream.pause();
          buffer.push(doc);
          counter++;
          // log(doc);
          try {
            if (counter > 10000) {
              await Case.insertMany(buffer);
              buffer = [];
              counter = 0;
            }
          } catch (e) {
            stream.destroy(e);
          }
          stream.resume();
        })
        .on("end", async () => {
          try {
            if (counter > 0) {
              await Case.insertMany(buffer);
              buffer = [];
              counter = 0;
              resolve();
            } 
          } catch (e) {
            stream.destroy(e);
          }
        });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    process.exit();
  }
};

exports.scrapingData = async (req, res, next) => {
   const url = "https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv";
   const path = Path.resolve(__dirname, "files", "covid-data.csv");

   const response = await Axios({
     method: "GET",
     url: url,
     responseType: "stream",
    });

   response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   response.data.on("end", () => {
     resolve(updateMongoRecords());
     next();
   });

   response.data.on("error", (err) => {
     reject(err);
   });
  });
 };
```

And  getCases.js inside **controllers/cases**  I have:

```
const Case = require("../models/case");

exports.getCases = async (req, res) => {
   const cases = await Case.find().then((cases) => res.json(cases));
};
```

With this code I am able to fetch in the route /cases all the cases in the client side (like postman) and it shows all of them. But the problem is that I can´t make any other requests (like signing out, which works fine if I don´t make the get request for the cases like before) afterwards because client (postman) gives the error: GET http://localhost:5000/signout
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000

in case you want to see the code for signout is like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const { signup, signin, signout } = require("../controllers/auth");
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/signup", userSignupValidator, signup);
router.post("/signin", userSigninValidator, signin);
router.get("/signout", signout);
```

inside **controllers/auth.js**:

```
exports.signout = (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie("t");
  return res.json({ message: "Signout successfully done" });
};
```

Any help on this??

Comment: Make sure the port you are trying to listen is not being used by another instance/process.

Comment: @Azevedo I´m able to  make any other requests to port 5000. But once I make the request for the /cases, then any other request afterwrds gives error. Do you think it may be because I am not letting the middleware funct scrapingData, or getCases continue the flow? using wrong the funct next... or something similar..

Comment: "Do you think it may be because I am not letting the middleware funct scrapingData, or getCases continue the flow?" -- very unlikely. You might be trying to listen to the same port twice in your code.

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` have nothing to do with midllewares.

Comment: @Azevedo all routes are pointing to port 5000, but the only which creates problems is the /cases one (here I am scraping the web, download a file, and push the data from the file into mongodb) but it seems that when it finishes pushing data, it doesn´t let any other request to happen. It may mean that this process is still running on that port and is blocking any requests coming to it? Don´t know what I´m doing wrong.